# Is it possible to defer member variable initialization to inherited class without modifying the parent class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, initialization

I'm having a specific problem which I've converted into the following [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
    public:
        Foo(int v) : val(v) {}

        int get_val() const
        {
            return val;
        }

    private:
        int val;
};

class Parent {
    public:
        Parent() : member(0) {}

        const Foo& get_member() const
        {
            return member;
        }

    protected:
        Foo member;
};

// Nothing above this line should be changed

class Child : public Parent
{
    public:
        // This doesn't work (compile error)
        //Child() Parent::member(1) {}

        // Nor does this (also a compile error)
        //Child() this->member(1) {}
};

int main()
{
    Child x;
    std::cout << x.get_member().get_val() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This example demonstrates the issue I'm having in a larger software project where I'm inheriting from an external library but *need to directly initialize one of the parent's member variables*.

Unfortunately, the Parent class does not have a constructor which parameterizes its member's initialization.

If the `Parent` class had a constructor of the form

```
Parent(int val) : member(val) {}
```

then I could write a `Child` constructor as

```
Child() Parent::Parent(1) {}
```

but that is not the case for me.

**Question**: Is it possible to defer the initialization of a parent's member variable to an inherited class? If so, how?

Comment: No.  The base class has to be completely constructed before the derived class even starts to be constructed.  You can't just set the member in the derived class constructor body?

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks, and no I can't. The parent class initializes its member with a default parameterization that sets up some network connections. These parameters cannot be altered after initialization.

Comment: Then how do you expect to be able to set base class member if there is no way to set it?

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm not expecting anything. I'm asking if there's a way for the child class to override the Parent's default initialization.

Comment: Ah, unfortunately, no.  You don't get to create a new constructor for the base class.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks, I thought this may be the case but hoped I was wrong.

Comment: So the problem is that `Parent() : member(0) {}` is really more like `Parent() : member(/* Something expensive and/or unchangeable */) {}`? Unfortunately, no, you can’t. The closest you could come is, in the body of the `Child` constructor, saying `member.~Foo(); new(&member) Foo{42}` in the body of the constructor. I think that causes undefined behavior, but if it doesn’t (or maybe even if it does but the compiler doesn’t do any optimizations to it) it’ll almost do what you want.

Comment: Perhaps a constructor in the base with the necessary parameters?

Comment: @Daniel H That right. It's certainly an interesting suggestion. I hadn't thought of explicitly invoking the destructor. If this isn't undefined behavior it may meet my needs I'll have to check.

Comment: @Charles Unfortunately I can't modify the base class. In practice I could technically add a new constructor to the library header file but I have good reasons to want to avoid changing the base class.

Comment: @jodag _"Unfortunately I can't modify the base class."_ In case they left you with any reasonable design, my answer could be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to defer the initialization of a parent's member variable to an inherited class? If so, how?

The parent class's member variable is either initialized in its member initialization list or in the body of the constructor. The child class cannot initialize the parent class's member variable in its initializer list -- that is not allowed by the language. The best you can do, it seems, is to set the value of the parent class's member in the body of the child class's constructor.

Example:

```
struct foo
{
   int a;
};

struct bar : foo
{
   bar() : a(0) {} // Not allowed
};
```

but

```
struct bar : foo
{
   bar() { a = 0; } // Allowed
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to initialize `Parent::member` in the `Child` class constructor body (again):

```
class Child : public Parent
{
    public:
        Child() {
            Parent::member = 1;
        }

};
```

See the [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/504779fb529e0c63).

---

As it was clarified in comments, you aren't supposed to *assign* the 
`Parent::member` variable.

In such case (let's assume the design was at least something useful),
you usually have the ability to apply a setter for certain properties of the parent class member's instance:

```
class Foo {
    Foo(const& Foo) = delete;
    Foo& operator=(const& Foo) = delete;
public:
    Foo() = default;
    int property() const;
    void property(int newVal);
};

class Parent {
protected:
    Foo member;
public:
    Parent() = default;
};

class Child : public Parent {
public:
    Child() {
        Parent::member.property(1);
    };
};
```

Comment: It may be too narrow, I could expand it more but the question is about overriding the parent's initializer. In this answer the parent still initializes `Foo` to 0, then the Child creates a new instance of `Foo` with a value of `1` and copies it to `member`. I'm actually a little surprised this runs as I thought that `=` form of constructor initialization only worked for during initialization.

Comment: That's an assignment, not an initialisation. It "works" because `Foo` has a converting constructor.

Comment: Why aren’t you supposed to assign to the `Parent::member` variable? If they didn’t want it assigned to they would have made it `private`.

Comment: @DanielH Ask the OP please, that's not the point apparently. That's how many _Component Frameworks_ solve the problem BTW.